# VSCode API: change workbench configuration, workspace.getConfiguration update editor.fontFamily does nothing?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm still new to writing VSCode extensions, so I'm trying something (that I think is) basic: changing the font family by clicking something on the status bar.

I found the following code snippet which prints the current font of the editor

```
const workbenchConfig = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('editor');
const currentFont = workbenchConfig.get('fontFamily');
console.log(currentFont);
```

but when I add

```
workbenchConfig.update('fontFamily', 'Arial');
```

it seems to do nothing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code works for me.  I assume you do have the `Arial` font installed.  Put an `await` in front of the `workbenchConfig.update` line to see it change before going to the next breakpoint.

Comment: @Mark yea, if i change the value of editor.fontFamily manually in settings.json, and then save the file, the font does change to Arial. I change it to something like this: `async function updateFont() {  await workbenchConfig.update('fontFamily', 'Arial'); } updateFont();` but it still does nothing

Comment: I forgot to mention I have this `async function activate(context) {` so just putting an `await` in form of your original line of code is enough, you don't need to call a separate `async` function if you don't want to.

Comment: in my case, having it in a separate async function is fine, but im also trying to understand your approach: i changed my 'export function activate` to `async function activate` and now the entire function doesnt run when i run the extension (I have some console.log in the beginning). how am i supposed to 'activate' (I guess?) an `async function activate`?

Comment: Either of the activation events `"*"` or  `"onStartupFinished"` for the purpose of testing - if your `update` code isn't in a command handler.